# Stopping a journey while an email send is taking place (throttled)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, send-throttling

Bit of an edge case here but in a live journey, a stakeholder wants to limit the number of emails sent via an engagement split as it's for a survey and they have a cap on the number of responses they want to receive (it's just a simple resend to those in the flow who did not open the initial email).

As the journey is live and running, my thinking is that we could apply a throttle in the delivery settings for the email activity with low-ish hourly rates, then when the stakeholder is happy to stop, we stop the journey (it's the last activity in the journey).

This will eject all contacts from the journey but if the email is throttling, will it stop this too (if yes, then this is the desired outcome)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stop a Journey, the triggered sends associated with the email activities will also be stopped, any subscribers in the queue will simply be abandoned and not sent to.